# How to differentiate data to be read between two tables when username and password is passed?

Tags: php

I am using volley in my mobile development login and instead of one table, I used two.

At first I was having trouble because my login process only shows the data of the client. When I put on my username and password as client, it does show but when I use an username and password from the stylist, still a client's data shows. Now I discovered it's from my main menu's problem because I have a php code for reading details and what is there is only reading the client's table. What I am needing help for now is how to correctly read the data of the two tables and pass it for my main menu?

This is my readDetail.php

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$id = $_POST['id'];
require_once 'connect.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id=$id";
$response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// HOW CAN I ALSO SELECT FROM STYLIST AND GO INSIDE THE QUERY
// FOR PASSING THE DATA? MY SQL QUERY IS ONLY FOR CLIENT AND THIS
// IS WHY I ONLY GET DATA FROM CLIENT. CAN SOMEONE POINT ME OUT
// WHAT TO QUERY TO ALSO PASS FOR THE STYLIST DATA?

$result = array();
$result['read'] = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1){

    if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)){
    $h['name']          = $row['name'];
    $h['phone_number']  = $row['phone_number'];
    $h['gender']        = $row['gender'];
    $h['address']       = $row['address'];
    $h['occupation']    = $row['occupation'];
    $h['birth_date']    = $row['birth_date'];
    $h['user_type']     = $row['user_type'];
    $h['image']         = $row['photo'];

    array_push($result["read"], $h);

    $result["success"] = "1";

    $result["message"] = "success";
    echo json_encode($result);
    }

}else{

    $result["success"] = "0";
    $result["message"] = "$sql";
    echo json_encode($result);

}



}


?>
```

Comment: Are you **sure** that `while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)){` and `if(password_verify($password,$colPassword1)){` are passed? if not, then the old array will be used

Comment: What is the value of `$response["success1"]` when you receive the response ?

Comment: how can I check it out sir? It seems that when I logged into an stylist account with the id of 2, logs in the account of the client with the id of 2.

Comment: I might know now what is the problem sirs. I'll try to change the context of my question because now I have realized that in my main menu, my read.php contains a query of getting the ID and just calling the table of clients which is why only the clients would show up. I hope I can be helped out from this.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id=$id` am I missing something?

Comment: this question has been solved sir. :) thanks for worrying

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved by also adding a usertype to each of my tables. also passing to their parameters and bringing if statements into it so it defines what table to open :) hihi